# Run npm from subdirectories on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I have a project which contains 2 subprojects:

- First is the API
- Second is the client

And both of these projects have their own dependencies mapped in their own `packages.json` files, which is placed in each subdir.

So the question is how to run `npm install` from sub directories on heroku?

I tried putting something like this in the main npm file

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd my_subdir; npm install"
}
```

But it doesn't work, showing `can't cd to my_subdir`

Comment: Why are you not create a separate Heroku app for each project?

Comment: Customer ask to deploy it to the single subdomain

Comment: I am not sure I understand what that means. Both are on a single domain, and in Heroku you only have one `web` process, so... which of them is it? Can you describe your *desired* deployment topology (what runs where, and listens on what ports, to what protocols, and talks to whom?)

Comment: In 2022 it works for me with `cd my_subdir && npm install`.

Answer (score 6):

Utilize npm's `--prefix` option:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "npm install --prefix ./my_subdir"
}
```